# django query generate LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Tags: django, join, orm

I try to do a simple query on my app but the result is wrong because Django ORM generate a LEFT OUTER JOIN . But I'd like the result of an INNER JOIN

Here is a part of my model :

```
class Application(models.Model):
    """ Une application """
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    app_pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)


class Event(models.Model):
    """ Evenement status """
    STATUS = (
        ('OK', 'OK'),
        ('KO', 'KO'),
        ('DEGRADE', 'DEGRADE'),
    )

    app = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_start = models.DateTimeField()
    status_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    status_global = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS,default='OK')
```

I tried to retrieve all the 'application' objects having an "opened event" (which means an event that has a Null 'status_end' value) :

This simple SQL query works :

```
select a.app_name from  event e, application a where a.id = e.app_id and e.status_end is null;
```

I wrote this django code :

```
apps_querysset = Application.objects.filter(event__status_end__isnull=True)
```

However, this code gererates a LEFT OUTER JOIN, so there are lot's of 'application' objects returned.

```
SELECT "appstat_application"."id", "appstat_application"."app_name", "appstat_application"."app_pub_date", "appstat_application"."app_type_id", "appstat_application"."app_site_id" FROM "appstat_application" LEFT OUTER JOIN "appstat_event" ON ("appstat_application"."id" = "appstat_event"."app_id") WHERE "appstat_event"."status_end" IS NULL
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an extra argument to the filter to make sure that the related `event` is not null.

```
apps_querysset = Application.objects.filter(event__isnull=False, event__status_end__isnull=True)
```

Comment: In your original query, Django returns rows where `event` is not null and `event.status_null` is null, and also rows where `event.status_end` is null because `event` is null. Adding the extra argument to the filter excludes the second case.